# what is the significance of the ACL value being a complement of UMASK value?

Tags: umask

From the description section of `man 2 umask` command, it says

> For example, the following default ACL is equivalent to a umask of 022:
>
> `u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x`

What's the significance of having another value which is a complement of UMASK instead of umask itself as an ACL value?

Comment: Because umask has always been, confusingly, the ones-complement of what it lets through. ACL is the same way as file modes.

Comment: In that manpage it says that when the parent dir has a default ACL, the umask is **ignored** and goes on to explain what default ACL creates the same effect as a umask of 022 -- considering that, I have trouble understanding the point of your question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor why is it confusing that a bit**mask** is *masking* bits (turning them off)? I have a strange feeling of déjà-vu -- we already beat this horse to death.

Comment: @mosvy thanks to you, I have come a long way to comprehend this concept. By default ACL equals ~umask, however I can no longer ask why because the umask (022 by default) is determined by Inode(s) specifications...way beyond my understanding (for now). I still don't understand why the default ACL (ACL value of the parent folder)  is the complement of umask value (octal 022 by default), I guess it's for bits operations tricks?!